# Internally how do fragment receives application's context (internal working)

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

> I am not asking for implementation or anything like that

I am very confused about how the fragment receives the context from Activity. I try to dig deep in Activity & Fragment inner working and all I can narrow it down is to  FragmentHostCallback but I am unable to understand how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

this way you can get applicationcontext() inside a fragment

Comment: Hello, as mentioned in the title & description, I wish to know the internal working of the context sharing. I don't need implementation or anything close to it. Just wanna know how the context is shared between activity & fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` has method `getContext()` that calls `FragmentHostCallback` host (`Activity` or `Fragment` to which is current `Fragment` attached) and returns `Context` of the host.

Comment: Hii, thanks for the reply. Here is the thing that I am having difficulty understanding, Fragment class has a variable **FragmentHostCallback mHost** but where is it initialized or inflated (not sure of right word) with the host's context/application etc.

Comment: @SakshamKhurana good question. Since `FragmentHostCallback` is abstract class you will not find initialization of mHost. I guess, it hides into `Fragment` constructor into the methord `initLifecycle()` and into class `FragmentController` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `beginTransaction()` methods

Comment: Looks like `FragmentController` class responses for the mHost instance in the future `Fragment`

Comment: It is very complicated to understand since most of the things that we are aware of are initialized/implemented somewhere in the code before being used. Maybe Android itself is handling this or something else but the code the developers wrote works good but very complex to decompile.

Comment: Principles of Encapsulation and Abstraction at their finest :)

Comment: But I still believe it's possible to find a needed answer after a good code and docs research